# Allowing wireless Internet but restricting LAN access

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing

The following diagram represents my current network.

[image: networkmap]

I would like for the Phone and the Laptop both on wireless to have internet access but not access to the other PCs/shares.

I have access to routing tables in both the cable router 10.0.0.1 and the wireless router

any ideas?

--edit

router models:

- wired : ASUS RX3042H
- wireless : Linksys WRT54G (default Firmware)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the router supports VLANs, you could put the two devices into separate ones, giving wireless access but no ability to see each others' shares. What's your router make/model?

Edit: Since you have now added that you have a Linksys WRT54G router, check out the version number and then see the following page at the OpenWrt site - if you fancy taking this route (ha - 'route'  geddit!?), you might be able to install a version of OpenWrt that gives you VLAN functionality.

http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start#linksys

Edit2: Just found this page too: http://hardy.dropbear.id.au/blog/2008/02/hosting-multiple-wireless-networks-on-openwrt

Comment: no VLAN afaik, I was thinking of routing 10.0.0.* (except 10.0.0.1) to  a unavailable gateway or one that doesn't know where to send 10. traffic

Answer (score 2):

Put your Internet into the wireless router, and then put the wired router's WAN side on the LAN side of the wireless router.  That way the wired router will firewall the wireless LAN clients from the wired network.